# How can I exclude a range of values when generating random numbers?

Tags: unity, c#

If you are using `Random.range` to generate values, is there any way to exclude some values within the range (for example: pick a number between 1 and 20, but not 6 through 8)?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of throwing away numbers you don't want, you can pretend you want a number from one slightly smaller range, and then map it into the 2 ranges you want:

```
float val = Random.Range( 1, 20 - 8 + 6 );
if ( val >= 6 ) val += 2;
```

Comment: This is clever and probably the best solution.

Comment: the problem is that this becomes a code mess when you want to work with multiple excluded ranges and variable ranges.

Answer (score 3):

You could generate a list of values you want to use, and then pick one at random.

Create values:

```
int[] values = new int[17] { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 };
```

Get a random value:

```
   int value = values[Random.Range(0, values.Length)];
```

Comment: What if the OP wants to generate a random number between 10 and 100? You're going to create an array containing those 90 numbers?

Comment: I probably wouldn`t create an array with the values no, more than likely not depending on the case.

Comment: Your answer shows otherwise

Comment: I am providing a solution to his question, you don`t have to get all upset over this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should go with a solution like this:

```
    int[] validChoices = new int[n]= {1,3,5, whatever until n occurrences};

    private int GetRandom(){
         return validChoices[Random.Range(0, validChoices.Length)];
    }
```